# "waiting on daemon synchronization to finish" Issue

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

In the GUI, it pops up "waiting on daemon synchronization to finish" but has been saying this for over an hour now. Am I being too impatient? In the past, it usually syncs up in a couple minutes. I am running it on windows 10 with a SSD if that helps. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is your firewall blocking it. Add it to the accepted programs in your firewall

Comment: If its windows, when you open firewall program, it will have check boxes to allow Monero. Check the boxes for public and private, on all the monero stuff, such as monerod, monero GUI

Comment: how to start the monerod separately from the GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Try starting the monerod separately from the GUI instead of starting the daemon within the GUI.  You should be able to more easily troubleshoot any issues you are experiencing with the daemon with its console messages showing on the screen.

Depending on your Internet connection it may take a while to download and sync the blockchain.

If you run monerod in a separate window, you can type "status" to see:

[image]